# My query in mysql is correct but there is something wrong in my code when I am applying it to VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

My query is correct in mysql but there is something wrong in my code when I am applying it to VB.net. Im using textpass.Text as a textbox.

```
    cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO errorlog(pword) VALUES ('Wrong','" & 
    Trim(txtpass.Text) & "'", con)
```

This is my working query in my sql
INSERT INTO pcba_info.errorlog(pword) VALUES ('Wrong ');

Comment: errorlog(pword) is one field name but pass two values

Comment: You're using string concatenation to build a database query. There is really no circumstances under which that won't hurt you in a very painful way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO errorlog(pword) VALUES ('Wrong','" & 
    Trim(txtpass.Text) & "'", con)
```

**errorlog(pword)**  ---> Here your specifing single column name but

**VALUES ('Wrong','" & Trim(txtpass.Text) & "'"** -----> your passing two values

So its throw error